# Compile error: "no matching function for call to" when returning static_cast reference

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, g++, static-cast

I have this compile error `no matching function for call to ‘Color::Color(Component&)’` on this templated method :

```
template<typename U>
inline U& getObject(const std::string& key)
  {
    return (static_cast<U>(*(_map.at(key))));
  }
```

I call it like that (components is of my type containing my map) :

`components.getObject<Color>("Color").getColor();`

**Color inherit from Component** and **_map** is a map of string and **Component*** (pointer on Component).

I have a lot of types derivating from Component and I store a pointer to them in my map. But when I try to get a Component from the map and cast it to a specific type to use it, I get the compile error above. I don't understand why.

Comment: Try static casting to a U&

Comment: Damn that worked, I can't believe I haven't though about that, thank you verry much, it is time I get some sleep

Comment: @Redleouf, was that a typo or did you not think of that as a possible answer when you posted the question?

Comment: A bit of both, I usually try those kind of things but I am actually pretty tired. Now that I see it, it actually make sence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a lot of types derivating from Component and I store a pointer to them in my map. But when I try to get a Component from the map and cast it to a specific type to use it, I get the compile error above. I don't understand why.

Because your function is coded wrong.

Your function is retrieving a `Component*` pointer from the map, dereferencing the pointer to access just the `Component` portion of the object (not the full derived type), and is then trying to construct a *temporary* instance of the derived class with the `Component` as input.

In other words, your example is essentially doing this:

```
inline Color& getObject(const std::string& key)
{
    TComponent *pcomp = _map.at(key);
    Color tmp(*pcomp); // <-- error here
    return tmp;
}
```

The error means that your `Color` class does not have a constructor that accepts a `Component` as input, so it fails to compile.

Even if the code did compile, it would still be wrong, because you are returning a *reference* to a temporary object that gets destroyed when the function exits, so the caller will end up with a dangling reference to invalid memory.

As @MikeVine stated in a comment, you can write the function like this to fix it:

```
template<typename U>
inline U& getObject(const std::string& key)
{
    return static_cast<U&>(*(_map.at(key)));
}
```

And that would work, as it eliminates the construction of a temporary object, and returns a reference to the existing object stored in the map.

You could also write the function like this instead:

```
template <typename U>
inline U& getObject(const std::string& key)
{
    return *(static_cast<U*>(_map.at(key)));
}
```

This code casts the `Component*` pointer to a `U*` pointer first before then dereferencing it to access the derived class object.

If you are not sure at runtime whether the requested component is actually the requested type, you could add some extra error handling to make sure before returning it:

```
template <typename U>
inline U& getObject(const std::string& key)
{
    U *ptr = dynamic_cast<U*>(_map.at(key));
    if (!ptr) throw std::invalid_argument("");
    return *ptr;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
template<typename U>
inline U& getObject(const std::string& key)
{
    return dynamic_cast<U&>(*(_map.at(key)));
}
```